# Velocity of light in different directions

Tags: speed-of-light, one-way-speed-of-light

From what I understand, we have not been able to measure unidirectional speed of light. It is said that theoretically it is possible for light to travel at c/2 in one direction and infinity speed in the opposite.

This brings me to the question if it is possible to measure this unidirectional speed of light by observing space in all directions. The direction where the speed of light is if c/2 should appear very old since we are just starting to receive it's light whereas the direction where it's infinite should appear extremely young.

Even if the difference in speed of light in opposite directions is not so extreme, is there a way to study patterns of space to identify which direction appears older and which younger?

Comment: https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/august-2015/the-age-of-the-universe The CMB shows uniformity in any direction with small fluctuations .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Features

Comment: Basis this can we say light has equal speed in all directions?

Comment: No, that the axiom that light has the same velocity in both directions cannot be disputed by watching the timing of light coming all around us,